# Can you redeploy an Android application via Intellij 9 Ultimate's Android support?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-emulator

I know that eclipse can do this, can Intellij via the new Android support do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just Run the application (**Shift+F10**), IDEA issues `pm install -r` device shell command and automatically restarts the application. It's the only action you need in order to test the new version of your application because Make is invoked automatically before Run by default.

If you have more than one Run configuration for different emulators (when you want to test under different resolutions and locales), then it's handy to use **Alt+Shift+F10** to quickly select the desired configuration from the pop-up before Run.

Emulator is never restarted, just the application is redeployed, so it's really fast.

Note that the Run panel will have only the most recently invoked configuration output, if you want to keep multiple configurations, just **Pin** the tab in the Run panel. Logcat panel allows to choose the Device from the drop-down menu.